# jquery click event does not fire on button elements in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

Using:

- Visual Studio 2013
- MVC5
- jQuery 1.10.2

The .click() event for `<button>` elements does not get called on an iPhone. This is the case for all `<button>` elements throughout my MVC project. It has been tested on multiple iPhones (iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 devices), so it does not seem to be an isolated issue.

It also has been tested on a PC with Firefox, IE, and Chrome and works as expected. It has also been tested on Android devices and Windows phone, and the .click() event works as it should. I cannot determine if this is a Safari, Safari Mobile, iPhone, or iOS issue.

I have found on Stack Overflow discussions about iOS devices sometimes do not work on elements that are not inherently clickable unless you add css styling to turn the cursor to a pointer (`cursor : pointer`). However, this workaround still does not work for `<button>` elements.

I think it is worth mentioning that the .click() event fires as it should on iPhone devices when an anchor tag (`<a>`) is used and styled to resemble a button.

Has anyone experienced this, and if so, know of a work around? I know I can change all of the `<button>` elements to `<a>` tags and that's what I will do if I have to. But I would like to understand why this is happening and if there is something I am doing to cause the issue. Many thanks.

Below is a snippet of the markup and jquery code I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#taskContainer').on('click', '#btnSave', function (event) {
        console.log('save button clicked');
    });
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="taskContainer">
  <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use return false at the end of click trigger:

```
$('#taskContainer').on('click', '#btnSave', function (event) {
    console.log('save button clicked');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @Zheka- thanks for the suggestion. Adding "return false" at the end of the click trigger still does not work.